# how do i parse an array element within double-quotes

Tags: php, variables

Is there more elegant way of escaping array elements:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = '".$someArray['somename']."'");
```

Something more like

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = '$myname'");
```

So avoiding the annoying '". ."'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = '{$someArray['somename']}'");
```

Comment: @Teodor Talov You're welcome! By the way, you might want to change `Escape` to something like `Parse` in the title as `escape` is normally used in the sense of *escaping special characters* like in `mysql_real_escape_string` to prepare your data for use in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = '{$foo[bar]}'");
```

But I would advise against it or any other parsed string, it's slower than concatenation and is much harder to read in some IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myname = $someArray['somename'];
mysql_query("SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = '$myname'");
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was trying to avoid declaring another variable. I was looking for something that saves me "" and lines of code, but thanks.